# Помогите расширить регулярное выражение для валидации email

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение

```
!preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $string )
```

Нужно в него добавить поддержку специального символа собаки `@` и точки `.`, так как емайл он не пропускает, а также, если возможно, поддержку кириллицы.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если только два символа - собачка и точка, тогда так

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9@.]+$/", $string)
```

экранировать точку внутри квадратных скобок не нужно.

Если нужна поддержка кириллицы, тогда можно так

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]+$/", $string)
```

Но скорее всего не заработает. (все завязано на юникод). Тогда с большой вероятностью поможет флажек `/u`:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]+$/u", $string)
```

Но тут есть одна тонкость ещё. Строка от браузера может приходить к примеру в cp1251, а на сервере скрипты в utf-8 или кои. И регулярки с кириллицей работать не будут (или будут, но "неожиданно" и неправильно). Рекомендация - переводите все в одну кодировку.

Comment: а возможно как то конвертирировать в UTF-8 проверять, а потом обратно конвертировать.

Comment: т.е. получается мне нужно знать, что приходит от сервера и какую кодировку отправляет клиент? У меня в header уcтановлена UTF-8 , так же сам файл сохранен в UTF-8

Comment: да, нужно знать кодировки. Но как по мне, лучше везде держать utf-8, это позволяет избегать многих проблем. 

Для преобразований кодировки используйте функцию [iconv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php) и родственные.

Comment: Как непатриотично вы забыли про букву `Ё`! Документация про неё помнит: _Диапазон допустимых символов кириллицы для доменов .РФ включает символы UTF—8 с символа «a» по символ «я» и дополнительный символ «ё»._ Поэтому русские буквы должны идти блоком `[А-яЁё]`.  Кстати, про дефис тоже забыли.

Comment: О дефисе ТС ничего не писал. А вот ё я вначале написал, но если уже делать поддержку кириллицы, то нужно писать и є, і, ї,ґ :). Кириллицу использует не только русский язык. ТС ничего о русском не писал, поэтому не нужно обвинять украинца в непатриотичности русскому языку:)

Comment: :-)  Да, кириллических доменов уже развелось много: `.укр`, `.рф`, `.сайт`, `.онлайн`, `.дети`, `.москва`, `.бг`, `.срб`, `.бел`, `.рус`, и внутри них действуют разные ограничения по алфавиту.  Тогда нужно добавить все символы кириллицы 0x400-0x45F и ещё украинский апостроф 0x2BC, который тоже разрешён в доменных именах.

Comment: Не мне лудше подойдет универсальный подход к кирилистическим символам, чтобы можно было и на русском сервере запускать  и на не русском. А на локальном поддержка \u и некоторые другие, не помню какие, не поддерживает.

Answer (score 3):

Если нет необходимости поддерживать кириллицу, то используйте нативные средства PHP для валидации данных [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   echo 'valid';
} else {
   echo 'invalid';
}
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/JOczqz)

Если через регексы, то:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\\w+[\\w\.\+\-]+)?\\w+@(\\w+\.)+\\w+$/iu', $email)) {
   echo 'valid'; 
}
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/zAxDpx)

Comment: У меня есть функция в классе, которая фильтрует данные. Она должна пропускать емайл точней символы в емайле @ и . как стандартные символы при этом  у меня для фильтарции имено емайла другая функция или filter_vars будет.

Answer (score 1):

@ добавляешь просто, как @, а точку в виде \., так как ее нужно экранировать обратным слешем.

Comment: типа такого ? !preg_match("/^@\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $string) Неработает : (

Comment: Так ты добавляешь условие, что @. должны стоять в начале, если хочешь в любом месте, добавь в квадратные скобки, если нужно в конце, то добавляй в конец